# Volley library W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Connected of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android

I have been trying yo figure out where this error lies but can't find it. Is there any ibe who can help me trace it?

thanks, family

***Here is my php code***

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $sql = "SELECT  * FROM students_table WHERE id = '$id'";

    $response = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);

    $result = array();
    $result['login'] = array();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1){

        $row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);

        if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){

            $index['id'] = $row['id'];
            $index['email'] = $row['email'];

            array_push($result['login'], $index);

            $result['success'] = "1";
            $result['message'] = "success";

            echo json_encode($result);

            mysqli_close($conn);

        }else {

            $result['success'] = "0";
            $result['message'] = "error";

            echo json_encode($result);

            mysqli_close($conn);
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
}
?>
```

**Here is my Android studio Code**

```
public void Login(final String idField, final String passwordField){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(java.lang.String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                Log.d("JSONR", jsonObject.toString());

                if (success.equals("1")){
                    for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String email = object.getString("email").trim();

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged In. \n"+email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        //Access WelcomePage Page if credentials are authenticated
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomePage.class));
                    }
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            })

    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("id", idField);
            params.put("password", passwordField);
            return params;
        }
    };

    //manage network requests using the volley request queue. I'm creating a request queue and passing in request objects
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**I've beeb trying to figure out where the error is from days but do not get it.
Any help?**

Comment: Can you print the response and see what is the value there ???

Comment: can't see any response except :                                                                                                          2019-02-05 15:26:01.166 13106-13106/com.example.inductionbuddy W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value Connected<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: So response contains some HTML tag like it shows <br which can't be converted to JSON object that's why it is throwing exception. It should be some string. See some examples in Google, u will understand.

Comment: Is the error from my php file? @Android Killer

Comment: Yes response coming from PHP is wrong. It should send response in JSON formatted string so that it can easily convert to JSON object. But it is sending response in html format, it may be some error or correct response but it should not be in html format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your php:

```
<?php require_once 'connect.php';

 //json response array
 $response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['password'])){ 

//receiving the post params
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);

//get the student
$student = getStudent($id, $password);
if ($student != false){

    //user is found
    $response["error"] = FALSE;
    $response["student"] ["id"] = $student["id"];
    $response["student"] ["email"] = $student["email"];


    echo json_encode($response);
}

else {
    //user is not found with credentials
    $response["error"] =TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Wrong Student or Password";

    echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else {

    //required post params is missing
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required paramaters missing";

    echo json_encode($response);

}

function getStudent($id, $password)
{
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * from students_table where username = '{$id}'";
    $student = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $rows   = mysqli_num_rows($student);
    $row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($student);

    if ($rows > 0 || password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
        return $row;

    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this is the error received after implementing the code:                Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd5/461/8645461/public_html/connect/connect.php:10) in /storage/ssd5/461/8645461/public_html/connect/connect.php on line 13
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Required paramaters missing"}

Comment: try changing
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
to
if (isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['password']))